# Java executing Linux script

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to execute a Linux script on Java that makes a file executable. The script contains the following:

```
#/bin/bash
chmod +x *
```

NOTE: The script is runnable (chmod +x)

My Java code contains the following:

```
try {
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./Scripts/execute.sh");
 }catch (Exception e1) {
     System.out.println("Exception: ");
     e1.printStackTrace();
 }
```

For some reason I don't seem able to run the script. I've tried before to run a simple script with 'echo 'hello'' and I was able to see the output. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: what is the error\exception ?

Comment: Seems that the script just does not get executed?! No exception

Comment: I used some code to make the output of the command and he doesn't give any error neither gives any kind of message.

EDIT: Weird, i changed the exec line to "chmod +x /path/to/file" and i was able to make the file executable...But without using the script

Comment: Where is the script located?

Comment: Inside the project directory in a subfolder named "Scripts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an other approach.

You can use NIO.2 for this. (Supposes that you use Java >= 7)

Have a look at [setPosixFilePermissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set%29)

You can use the Posix attribute to set the file permissions. [PosixFilePermissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermission.html)

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion but this against invoking linux shell commands from my program would be easier to implement, don't you think?

Comment: At least it should work :) Idk why the sh script does not work

Comment: And it really shouldn't be much work to implement it :)